# Combinatorics proof (any set of 16 numbers from 1 to 100 contains repeated sums)

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose that $A$ is a set of 16 distinct natural numbers and that $1\leq p\leq100$ for every $p$ in $A $.

Prove that $A$ contains 4 different numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, such that $a+b=c+d$.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What is $p$?  Are the numbers $a,b,c,d$ supposed to belong to $A$?

Comment: How many of $a,b,c,d$ are supposed to be distinct?

Comment: all of them are distinct

Comment: It would be nice to see some motivation for this, and some evidence that you have put some thought into it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean with motivation? I have worked on this problem for 4 hours. But i haven't found anything useful.

Comment: I mean, why have you worked on this problem, and not some other? Did you make it up? Did you find it somewhere? Is it part of a homework assignment? Does some other result depend on it? There is no shortage of mathematical problems a person could pose; why this one?

Comment: I went to a mathematical olympiad this morning. There where three problems. I solved two out of three, I couldnt solve this one. I want to know how to solve it because I feel like it may be useful in another olympiad

Comment: Good! That's what I like to see....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is number 17 of the introductory problems section in the book *102 Combinatorial Problems from the 
training of the USA IMO team* by Titu Andreescu and Zuming Feng.

Here is a paraphrase of their solution.

There are ${16\choose 2}=120$ pairs of numbers from $A$. Since
the  absolute  differences range from 1 to 99, there must be two different pairs 
$\{a,c\}$ and $\{d,b\}$ with $a-c=d-b$ and hence $a+b=c+d$.

The problem is that $\{a,b,c,d\}$ may not be distinct. Well, what could go wrong?
We may end up with pairs like $\{7,6\}$ and $\{6,5\}$. In this case, we may call 
the number 6 "bad". Generally, we call $a\in A$ a bad number if there exist 
$a_1<a<a_2\in A$ with $a_2-a=a-a_1$.

Note that if $a$ is bad for *two different pairs* of pairs, then we have a solution.
That is, if  $a_1<a<a_2\in A$ so that $a_2-a=a-a_1$ and 
$a_3<a<a_4\in A$ so that $a_4-a=a-a_3$, then we have $a_1+a_2=a_3+a_4$.
You can check that $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ really are distinct in this case.

So the only *real* problem are pairs of numbers in $A$ whose midpoint $a$ 
also belongs to $A$, such that no other pair has the same midpoint. 
There are at most 16 such troublesome pairs, so there are $120-16=104$ pairs left.
Applying the pigeonhole principle to this reduced set gives the solution.

Comment: how do you know that there are only 16 of those troublesome pairs and why is it a problem that $a$ belongs to $A$

Comment: There can be at most one "troublesome" pair for every $a\in A$.

Comment: It's a problem if $a$ belongs to $A$ because, as in the example, you'd have $7-6=6-5$ and you'd wind up with $7+5=6+6$ and you wouldn't have distinct $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** This solution is for the problem as originally posed, without the requirement that $a,b,c$, and $d$ be distinct. That requirement makes it significantly harder, and I’ll have to think about it a bit more if I have time.

(I’m assuming that you mean that if $p\in A$, then $1\le p\le 100$.) Here’s an extended hint.

Let $D=\{|a-b|:a,b\in A\text{ and }a\ne b\}$, the set of pair differences.

1. How many pairs $\{a,b\}\subseteq A$ are there with $a\ne b$?
2. If $1\le a\le 100$ for every $a\in A$, what numbers could be in $D$? How many such numbers are there?
3. Use the pigeonhole principle to find $a,b,c,d\in A$ such that $a-c=d-b$.

Comment: @Khromonkey: No, I’m asking what the possible values of $|a-b|$ are.

Comment: @Khromonkey: It’s conceivable that all of the duplicated distances occur in triples like $4,11,18$ (for distance $7$), in which case you don’t get four distinct numbers. Somehow that possibility has to excluded.

Answer (score 2):

a computer search shows that there is a set of 13 numbers between 1 and 100 with no four satisfying a+b=c+d: $$(1, 2, 12, 18, 22, 35, 43, 58, 61, 73, 80, 85, 87)$$ (and 87 is the lowest maximum that is achievable), but that the lowest possible maximum for a set of 14 positive integers with no a+b=c+d is 106: $$(1, 2, 7, 15, 28, 45, 55, 67, 70, 86, 95, 102, 104, 106)$$ so in fact, any set of 14 integers in the range 1 to 100 has repeated sums.
(I would have added this as a comment, rather than an answer, but I am new to math.stackexchange, so haven't accumulated the requisite reputation to comment)