# For any $18$ distinct two-digit numbers, are there four distinct numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a+b=c+d$ ? Can we make $18$ small?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I've known that the following proposition is true for $n=20$.

> **Proposition** : For any $n$ distinct two-digit numbers, there exists a set of four distinct numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a+b=c+d$.

Then, I began to try to find the minimum of $n$ such that the proposition is true. Then, I've got that the proposition is true for $\color{red}{n=19}$.

**Proof that the proposition is true for $n=19$** :

Let the given $19$ numbers be $a_1\lt a_2\lt \cdots\lt a_{19}$. Also, let $\{a_2-a_1,a_3-a_2,\cdots, a_{19}-a_{18}\}=\{b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_{18}\}$ where $b_1\le b_2\le\cdots\le b_{18}$.

Suppose that there exists no set of four distinct numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a-c=d-b$.

If $b_n=b_{n+1}$, then there exist $p,q\ (p\lt q)$ such that $a_{p+1}-a_p=a_{q+1}-a_q$, but from the supposition, $q=p+1$ has to hold. It follows from this that there are no three same numbers in $b_n$ and that 
$\sum_{k=1}^{18}b_k\ge 1+1+2+2+\cdots +9+9=90$, which contradicts that we have $\sum_{k=1}^{18}b_k=a_{19}-a_1\le 99-10=89$. **QED**

This is all I've been able to get so far. So, my question is the following :

> **Question** : How can we find the minimum of $n$ such that the proposition is true?

---

**Added** : Byron Schmuland proves that the proposition is true for $n=14$ under the condition that $a,b,c,d$ are not necessarily distinct. Also, he comments that we can prove that the proposition is true for $n=15$ under the condition that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct according to the solution for [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186866/combinatorics-proof-any-set-of-16-numbers-from-1-to-100-contains-repeated-sums).

What I mean in this question is that $a,b,c,d$ are **distinct**. (sorry, this might not be obvious. So, I add the word "distinct")

We now know that **the minimum of $n$ has to be less than or equal to $15$.**

Here, I'm going to write the proof for $n=15$ by getting the key idea from the above solution.

**Proof that the proposition is true for $n=15$** where $a,b,c,d$ are distinct :

Suppose that there exists no set of four numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a-c=d-b$. There are $\binom{15}{2}=105$ ways to choose $2$ numbers from the given $15$ numbers. From the supposition, each difference of their $2$ numbers are distinct except the case when $$i-j=j-k\tag1$$ where $i\gt j\gt k$. Here, for every $j$, there exists at most one $(i,k)$ satisfying $(1)$. This is because if there were distinct $(i,k),(i',k')$ such that $i-j=j-k,i'-j=j-k'$, then the four numbers $i,k,i',k'$ would be distinct and would satisfy $i-i'=k'-k$, which contradicts the supposition. Since $j$ can neither the maximum number nor the minimum number, the number of the patterns where $(1)$ happens is at most $15-2=13$.

Hence, if we eliminate at most $13$ sets of $2$ numbers, then each difference of the $2$ numbers from the remaining $105-13=92$ is distinct. However, the difference of $2$ numbers is either $1,2,\cdots, 88,89(=99-10)$, which is a contradiction. **QED**

**Added** : Byron Schmuland and Ross Millikan independently show eleven 2-digit numbers so that every pair has a different sum. So, we now know that the minimum $n_{\text{min}}$ of $n$ has to satisfy $\color{red}{12\le n_{\text{min}}\le 15}$.

Comment: I use the pigeon-hole-principle very rarely, but here it could be useful.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for the comment. I used the pigeon-hole-principle for $n=20$. (sorry I didn't write about that). We can make 177 nests and $\binom{20}{2}=190\gt 177$. But we have $\binom{19}{2}=171\lt 177$, so I couldn't find a way to use the principle for $n\le 19$. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186866/combinatorics-proof-any-set-of-16-numbers-from-1-to-100-contains-repeated-sums

Comment: What does 177 count? I get 89 "nests" so even $n=14$ should work, because ${14\choose 2}=91>89.$

Comment: Cool proof for $n=19$!

Comment: @mathlove One version of your problem says that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct, and the other version doesn't. The "distinct" version is a bit harder.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland:  The related question shows that $n \le 16$, because here we have restricted the range of numbers from that one.  The $177$ counts the possible sums of two numbers, from $10+11=21$ through $98+99=197$

Comment: Your 19-proof would work for 18 if the range of numbers were $10,\ldots,90$ or the like. We conclude $a_{18}-a_1>80$. Similarly, $a_{17}-a_1>71$, $a_{18}-a_2>71$ etc.

Comment: You can improve your approach to lower $n$ somewhat.  If you have two $1$'s in the series of $b_i$ you can't have two $2$'s.  That is because the two $1$'s have to come from $a_k, a_{k+1}=a_k+1, a_{k+2}=a_k+2$  Now you might have a single $2$ if $a_{k+3}=a_k+4$, but you can't have another one.  Similarly, if you have two $3$'s you can only have one $6$.  This will drive the minimum sum of the $b_i$'s upward, so it takes fewer of them to exceed $89$.  I haven't figured out how much better you can do.

Answer (score 3):

*Update:* The following solution and example are for a different problem
 where we don't insist that  $a,b,c,d$ are distinct.

---

**Proof for $n=14$**

Let $A$ be a set of 14 distinct 2-digit numbers. 
There are ${14\choose 2}=91$ pairs of numbers from $A$. Since
the  absolute  differences range from 1 to 89, there must be two different pairs 
$\{a,c\}$ and $\{d,b\}$ with $a-c=d-b$ and hence $a+b=c+d$.

---

On the other hand, here are eleven 2-digit numbers so that every pair has a different sum: {18, 35, 37, 39, 59, 71, 83, 86, 89, 94, 99}.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that your solution supposes that there can be the same number in $a,b,c,d$. Is this correct?

Comment: @mathlove Yes, that is possible. For *distinct* numbers, I get only get down to $n=15$. See the solution that I linked to above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I can understand that the proposition is true for $n=15$ under the condition that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct. So, I edited the question to add your result. (please let me know if what I added has something wrong.)

Comment: I tried a greedy approach, always adding the smallest number that didn't create a problem, which gave $\{10,11,12,14,17,22,30,39,48,62,81\}$ for eleven  I suspect that is the size of the largest set with distinct sums, but do not have a proof

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: I added the proof that the proposition is true for $n=15$ where $a,b,c,d$ are distinct. Thank you. Also, thank you for adding the eleven numbers.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thank you for adding the result. Very interesting.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for your example. My computing skills are close to nil, so I have no idea whether there are better algorithms to search for such sets. I find it a very interesting problem!

Comment: @hardmath:  you are correct, I missed that one.  $83$ does make it work.

Answer (score 0):

a computer search shows that there is a set of 13 numbers between 10 and 99 with no four satisfying a+b=c+d: $$(10, 11, 21, 27, 31, 44, 52, 67, 70, 82, 89, 94, 96)$$ but that the lowest possible maximum for a set of 14 integers >= 10 with no $a+b=c+d$ is 115: $$(10, 11, 16, 24, 37, 54, 64, 76, 79, 95, 104, 111, 113, 115)$$ so in fact, the optimum result is that any set of **14** two digit integers contains distinct $a, b, c, d$ with $a+b=c+d$.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: @XcoderX are you asking for the C code for the search or a description of the logic?  (I wrote it in Perl, but it was rather slow, so I manually translated the Perl to C to get better performance, so as a C program it's not well structured, but the logic is fine).  A comment is too short for either, so whichever you are looking for I will need to add another answer to provide it.

Comment: oh.  no.  i wasn't looking for a code.  I think i understand now.