# Ways of choosing $16$ integers from first $150$ integers such that there is no $(a,b,c,d)$ for which $a+b=c+d$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Here is a problem I found out recently:

> *In how many ways one can choose $16$ distinct positive integers from first $150$ positive integers such that there are no $4$ distinct ones $(a,b,c,d)$ for which $a+b=c+d$*?

### My approach:

> If $a+b=c+d$, then $a-c=d-b$. There are $149$ differences from the first $150$ positive integers. We have to choose $\binom{16}{2}=120$ differences. So, the answer is $\binom{149}{120}$.

---

I'm confused with my approach.
**Edit:** *My solution is not correct*.

So, what is the correct solution to the problem? And I noticed that it is hard to find out such $16$ integers. So, **if choosing $16$ such numbers is not possible**, how to prove that? Any helpful approach is welcome.

**Source**: The problem is self-made and inspired from a problem from the book *102 Combinatorial Problems: From The Training of The USA IMO Team* by *Titu Andreescu* and *Zuming Feng*.

Comment: Are there any?  If you do a greedy search, you get the Fibonacci sequence, and only get eleven numbers.

Comment: Didn't understand what you meant. Please post your full solution. @Empy2

Comment: Please explain your solution @LangDon

Comment: A greedy search means:  Include 1,2,3.  You can't have 4 because 1+4=2+3 but you can have 5.  You can't have 6 or 7 but can have 8.  So include every number you can without looking ahead.

Comment: As stated above if $a+b=c+d$ then $a-b=d-b$. So, if there are no $4$ distinct integers such that their difference is same then we are done. Since we have to choose from first $150$ positive integers, we have $149$ differences. Now note that since we have to choose $16$ integers, so there can be $\binom{16}{2}=120$ pairs whose differences are distinct. So, we can choose the differences in $\binom{149}{120}$, which should be the answer. Hope you get it @Empy2

Comment: @LangDon The condition you presented is a required condition, yet it's not sufficient. Better said, there's no guarantee that for any 120 numbers out of $1,2,\dotsb,149$ there exist $16$ numbers such that the pairwise differences of these numbers are equal to the foresaid 120 numbers. Your solution only assures that there are less than or equal to $\binom{149}{120}$ such 16-tuples.

Comment: Your answer is way off. There are only $\binom{150}{16}$ ways to choose the sixteen integers. Clearly not all of them work, so the answer must be a lot less. But $\binom{150}{16}<\binom{149}{120}$, so you are seriously overcounting.

Comment: I feel like the answer may be zero. Greedy search as suggested by @Empy2 is a good idea. Though it is not necessarily true that it gives the sequence $a_1 < a_2 < \ldots < a_k$ with minimal $a_k$ such that all pairs $\{a_i, a_j\}$ have distinct sums. For example, with k = 7 we have the set $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 14, 19\}$ which is 'better' than the greedy search result of $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21\}$. If it had been true that Greedy search was optimal then we'd know that $a_k$ must be at least the $k+1$th Fibonacci number so for $k=16$ that's $987 >> 150$. Surely Greedy is close enough to optimal...

Comment: @ChrisRussell I tend to agree, it is difficult to find a single set of 16 numbers that works. 13 is my best so far, though I'm not placing any bets, yet.

Comment: @Empy2 The greedy algorithm does not need to continue with the Fibonacci sequence. For example $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 30, 39, 53, 74, 95,128\}$ seems to work also.

Comment: Arithmetic progressions of length three are ok as subsequences.

Comment: [The optimal Golomb ruler with 15 tickmarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler#Known_optimal_Golomb_rulers) spans from $0$ to $151$. The proofs of optimality for those are brutal. Golomb rulers don't allow any repetitions while we can allow an arithmetic progression of length three, so it is not an equivalent question. Anyway, either there is a slick argument that 16 cannot be achieved or this is a truly cruel question.

Comment: Ive found dozens of 15s, starting with $1,2,3,144,147,150$, for example with 12,35,52,66,73,103,108,128,132

Comment: [A039836](http://oeis.org/A039836) may be useful, although it only goes up to $a(63)$.

Comment: Can you check the source? If it chooses from the first 100, then that's [an olympiad problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186866/combinatorics-proof-any-set-of-16-numbers-from-1-to-100-contains-repeated-sums/186870#186870).

Comment: This is a self-made problem inspired by that problem.

Comment: for every possible set {a,b,c} there are at most 3 possible values of d that break the a+b!=c+d restriction, namely, a+b+c-2X, where X can be a,b,c.

Comment: For what it's worth, here are sixteen with maximum 160, not 150:  $1, 2,3,22,38,42,71,82,96,104,130, 142,  147, 154,  157,  160$

Comment: @Empy2 here's a slightly better solution with maximum 158: $1,4,7,13,22,47,66,73,80,102,110,130,134,147,157,158$

Comment: Getting closer: $1,14,25,34,48,66,82,98,110,117,127,148,152,153,154,156$

Comment: So close: $1,3,5,16,27,37,55,58,75,83,102,116,139,145,146,151$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So if we remove the condition $b\ne c$ from the question, only then it becomes the *Golomb ruler* (alternatively, *Sidon sequence*) problem?

Comment: You were so close. Could you proceed further? @RobPratt

Comment: The question has been bountied two times and still no answer...

Comment: Another near miss (sum $223$ appears twice): $\{1,2,13,25,32,48,51,77,85,106,128,133,138,142,146,148\}$

Answer (score 9):

## There is a solution!

Despite my doubts for much of this time, expecting the answer to be that a solution could not be found without going above 150, it turns out that there *is* a valid solution.

The solution that I have found is:

$$
1,4,6,7,33,50,60,69,94,107,119,127,131,135,142,149
$$

I have confirmed that all 120 sums of two values are unique. Note that a second solution is the same as this, except with each value replaced with 150 minus the value.

The value was found by my code, after maybe 2 days of run time. The code is still running, so it may find more solutions.

---

### Previous observations...

To assist in seeking an answer to this, I have investigated the equivalent questions for smaller numbers. In particular, what's the smallest number of "first $n$ integers" that you need to be able to choose $k$ integers satisfying the condition. For each of the numbers presented here, I have used code to confirm that it cannot be done with a smaller range of values.

In the table below, the set of solutions are "up to reversal" - this is because, if you replace all values, $s$, in the solution with $n+1-s$, you get another solution, and thus all solutions come in equivalent pairs. For example, $[1,2,3,5,8]$ and $[1,4,6,7,8]$ are identical, up to reversal.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c} 
\hline\text{choose $k$ integers} & \text{from first $n$ integers} & \text{Solutions (up to reversal)} \\ \hline
5 & 8 & [1,2,3,5,8] \\ \hline
6 & 13 & \begin{array}{c}[1,2,3,5,8,13]\\ [1,2,3,7,10,13]\end{array} \\ \hline
7 & 19 & \begin{array}{c}[1,2,3,5,9,14,19]\\ [1,2,3,8,11,15,19]\end{array} \\ \hline
8 & 25 & [1,2,3,5,9,15,20,25] \\ \hline
9 & 35 & \begin{array}{c}[1,2,3,5,9,16,25,30,35]\\ [1,2,3,8,14,17,27,31,35]\\ [1,2,3,15,20,25,28,31,35]\end{array} \\ \hline
10 & 46 & [1,2,8,11,14,22,27,42,44,46] \\ \hline
11 & 58 & \begin{array}{c}[1,2,6,10,18,32,35,38,45,56,58]\\ [1,2,6,10,18,32,34,45,52,55,58]\end{array} \\ \hline
12 & 72 & \begin{array}{c}[1,2,3,8,13,23,38,41,55,64,68,72]\\ [1,2,12,19,22,37,42,56,64,68,70,72]\end{array} \\ \hline
13 & 87 & [1,2,12,18,22,35,43,58,61,73,80,85,87] \\ \hline
14 & 106 & \left[\begin{array}{c}1,2,7,15,28,45,55,67,\\70,86,95,102,104,106\end{array}\right] \\ \hline
15 & 127 & \left[\begin{array}{c}1,2,3,23,27,37,44,51,81,\\96,108,111,114,119,127\end{array}\right]\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Some insights:

1. The increase in $n$ needed to increase $k$ by 1 seems to grow each time (with the only exception being 13->19->25 - the differences between $n$ values go 5,6,6,10,11,12,14,15,19 - this is not overly surprising, but worth noting.
2. The density of sums within the possible range can be calculated relatively easily. There are $\frac{k(k-1)}2$ pairs within the set, and thus that many sums if no two are the same. There are $2n-3$ possible sums creatable from a pair of numbers between $1$ and $n$ (as the sum cannot be $1$, $2$, or $2n$). Therefore, the density is given by $\frac{k(k-1)}{2(2n-3)}$ - the resulting densities are (approximately) 76.9%, 65.2%, 60.0%, 59.6%, 53.7%, 50.6%, 48.7%, 46.8%, 45.6%, and 43.5%.
3. All optimal solutions found so far (accounting for reversal) can be written with $[1,2...$ at the start.
4. Interestingly, while a solution for $k=15$ can be found with $n=127$, no such solution can be found for $n=128$ if you require both 1 and 128 in the set.

Approaches I have used to try to find solutions:

1. A code that seeks the solution in an "additive" approach - find which values can be added to the existing set you have, and keep expanding until you run out of values, then backtrack and try a new value. With careful coding to ensure it minimises the search space reasonably well, this can find all optimal solutions for up to $k=14$ within a reasonable amount of time, if you input the correct $n$ in (and can similarly be used to confirm that no lower $n$ will work). However, for larger $n$, it becomes a lot more unwieldy.
2. A greedy code that seeks the solution in a "subtractive" approach - start with all possible values in the same set (so, 1 through 150 for the actual question), then remove numbers based on which ones will reduce the number of "collisions" (sums that appear multiple times) by the most - with some randomness where multiple numbers can achieve the same reduction... and then add numbers back if they don't substantially increase the number of collisions. This can find many solutions quite quickly for "easy" cases, but due to the random aspect, is also pretty slow to find optimal values for larger $n$. A non-random approach is likely to be very, very slow, as you start with a lot of numbers and there are a lot of options for removal.
3. Take a smaller solution, such as for $k=12$ ($n=72$), then rescale the numbers and try to fill the gaps. For example, multiplying the first $k=12$ solution by 2 gives $[2,4,6,16,26,46,76,82,110,128,136,144]$. From here, we can find that $[31,89,147]$ is capable of being added, for a total of $k=15$... but despite various attempts, I have not succeeded in reaching $k=16$ using this approach.

Comment: I confirm these "smallest $n$" values.  I had used integer linear programming to extend OEIS sequence [A039836](https://oeis.org/A039836) to $n=110$ a couple weeks ago.  The smallest $n$ values for $k=15$ and $k=16$ are at most $127$ and $151$, respectively.

Comment: I have updated after confirming that $n=127$ is the optimal value for $k=15$, with no further solutions identified. My code took about 23 hours to complete the run that did it (after spending a substantial amount of time working on optimisation techniques). This was spent because it seems that it takes about 10-50 times as long for each increment in $k$.

Comment: I have just updated with a solution! @RobPratt might be interested to see it, too.

Comment: Excellent!  Looks like 59 is a typo for 69.  With that correction, I confirm that it is valid.  Interesting that it doesn't contain 2 or 150.

Comment: @RobPratt - correct, it was a simple typo on my part as I copied it in. And yes, I've been able to confirm that there are NO solutions for $n<152$ that contain both 1 and 2. The only solutions found so far are the one you found for $n=151$, and the solution for $n=149$ that I've since found - the code is currently looking at solutions that begin with $[1,5,17...]$ - it's progressive, so it has checked all $[1,2,...]$, $[1,3,...]$, and $[1,4,...]$.

Comment: Congratulations.